# How do I define the window icon used by window managers?

Tags: icons, window-manager, titlebar

I would like to change the icons displayed in window title bars:

[image]

The window icons appear to be unrelated to the icons used by launchers and docks, as they don't follow the ones defined in their respective `.desktop` files. In the example above the lower window (Recoll) is lacking a proper icon and showing a stock one instead, even though its launcher comes with an icon.

So my question is: Where can I find these window icons in my filesystem and how do I define a new one for an application of my choice?

Comment: Related: [How to change a window icon in Openbox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1077359/396228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the icon is part of the theme, and should generally be the same icon as defined in the .desktop file. However, this really depends on the application. In many cases there won't necessarily be a file on the filesystem with the icon, as the icon will be embedded in the application itself.

So, it depends on what the application is doing in this case, as there are several ways for it to set the titlebar icons for its windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So as long as neither application nor icon theme come with an appropriate icon, there's no way of defining one of your own?

Comment: Even if the icon theme has an icon, the application may not be using it. It depends on the application. Some applications (such as Recoll mentioned in your question) may even need changes to the code.