# How to change a window icon in Openbox?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, window-manager, openbox

I would like to change the window icon of an already existing application on Lubuntu. By window icon, I mean the one that appears in the window title bar, and in lxpanel. By existing application, I mean one that is already running. I don't want to edit the source code of the application itself. I'm running Lubuntu 17.10 with LXDE, Openbox 3.6.1, and xdg-desktop-icon 1.1.0 rc3.

Usually, it seems that icons for applications are described by name, and then looked up in a database managed by xdg-desktop-icon and [xdg-icon-resource](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-icon-resource.html). The process by which icons are looked up is specified in the [FreeDesktop.org specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#icon_lookup), and there's some handy [scripts to get the icon filepath here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6090241).

There are a few tools which may do what I want. The first is [xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/). Unfortunately, it's unmaintained. I don't see a pre-compiled version anywhere and I'm not eager to spend time figuring out a build environment for dubious old code.

The other tools are [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) and [wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl). I think either of these should work:

```sh
xdotool search --name Geany set_window --icon-name help-contents
wmctrl -r Geany -I help-contents
```

Neither has any visible effect. However, wmctrl does change the value of _NET_WM_VISIBLE_ICON_NAME according to [obxprop](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.10/x/openbox.html#obxprop), and it seems like it sets WM_ICON_NAME according to [its code](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/89cb4cf5fd8b27058491fda8294b184f70b31076/cmd_set_window.c#L90).

Am I using xdotool and wmctrl properly? As I play with obxprop, it seems like WM_ICON_NAME is equivalent to the window title rather than the icon name. I don't see a way to do this with [OpenBox configuration files](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications). Is there another tool to do this?

Comment: --icon-name is, as you remark yourself at the end, indeed not intended for changing the icon. It is intended to contain a string, the WM_ICON_NAME property of a window, to label the application when it is minimized. Typically, the label will be shorter than WM_NAME, the "regular" Window title.